# What's the value of Thomae's function at integers?

Tags: functions, definition

In Calculus by Michael Spivak, a version of Thomae's function is given as
$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{for irrational $x$} \\
1/q, & \text{if $x=p/q$ in lowest terms}
\end{cases}$$

This function is first introduced in a discussion of limits, where it's confined to the interval $(0,1)$. Later, it comes up again when we're asked to show $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$.

What is the value of $f(0)$? What about $f(1)$?

I understand that neither of these values will affect the integral (nor will the value of $f$ at any isolated point). I'm just curious about the standard defined values of $f(0)$ and $f(1)$. Is $f(z) = 1$ for any integer $z$? Does this include $0$? Perhaps $f(0)$ is usually defined to be $0$?

Note: I'm **not** looking for help demonstrating the integrability of $f$. Just curious how $f$ is typically defined.

Comment: $7$ in lowest terms is $7/1$, so $f(7) = 1$.  Use the convention that $0$ in lowest terms is $0/1$, so $f(0)=1$.  Allowing inproper fractions, we can arrange that $f$ is periodic with period $1$.

Comment: @GEdgar: I agree, except that I would say that $0/1$ is not just a convention $-$ it follows from the definition: the greatest common divisor of $0$ and a strictly positive integer $n$ is $n$, so $0/n$ becomes $(0/n)/(n/n)=(0/1)$.

Comment: Thanks to you both!